# UINavigationController - Start with middle view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my application, I've 7 views and they are based on navigation.
When the app starts, I want to show the 3rd view in navigation.
So that user can navigate to 4th view as usual or user can navigate to 2nd view by clicking "Back" button on the top left.
How can I make my navigation controller show 3rd view directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `viewControllers` property and `popToViewController` method:

```
navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController, thirdViewController, ...., nil];
[navigationController popToViewController:thirdViewController animated:NO];
```